# Applying estimated transfer function to a signal to simulate channel

Tags: matlab, transfer

I'm trying to simulate an audio transmission channel from some samples: I have original recordings and the ones recorded with distortion. I'm using tfestimate() in order to obtain a transfer function estimate. But now I'm a little bit confused about how to apply it to create simulated distortion. What I tried to do is:

```
res = tfestimate(...)                     % get TF from clean and noisy record.
c = abs(ifft(res));                       % convert to time domain
out = conv(signal, c);                    % filter
wavwrite(out, 16000, 16, '/tmp/out.wav'); % dump
```

but I'm not happy with the result, it just sounds very differently.

is there a better way to apply the transfer function estimate "res" to the input "signal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, your "original recordings and the ones recorded with distortion" were recorded at the same time, right?  And the distortion process does not add noise?

Instead of computing the transfer function in the frequency domain with `tfestimate` and then trying to invert it, it would be more direct to compute the FIR Wiener filter that turns the original recording into the distorted version.

Alternatively, you could try to fit the transfer function returned by `tfestimate` and then turn it into a time-domain filter.  The function `invfreqs` is a good place to start; it will fit a ZPK model to the measured frequency response.

Comment: yes, the recordings are synchronized as good as possible.
the distortion as described above modifies the input signal somehow, but the result doesn't sound as expected.
thank you for the hint with the ZPK model! can you also point me to the functions I need for the FIR Wiener filter estimation?

Comment: For the invfreqs technique: Do invfreqs, then make a zpk model, then use c2d ("continuous to discrete"), then I think tfdata will give you the [a,b] coefficients for y=filter(b,a,x). Maybe you could do invfreqz instead of invfreqs and skip the c2d.

Comment: Thank you very much! The invfreqz()+filter() seem to do exactly what I intended to!

Comment: Just curious, how did the filter created with invfreqz()+filter() sound? In the past, I've generally seen the TF of analog audio gear measured in the time domain using impulse signals.